# How to throw an exception in Antlr grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

I have this kind of a grammar,

```
locationPath returns [CustomParser xpathParser]  
    :^(LOCATION_PATH relativeLocationPath {**Want to throw a exception if this condition matches**})
    |^(LOCATION_PATH absoluteLocationPath {$xpathParser=$absoluteLocationPath.xpathParser;})
    ;
```

What is the way to do it?  I tried with this one

```
locationPath returns [CustomParser xpathParser]  
    :^(LOCATION_PATH relativeLocationPath {throw new Exception})
    |^(LOCATION_PATH absoluteLocationPath {$xpathParser=$absoluteLocationPath.xpathParser;})
```

But with this one the generated code gives compile Error. Because that method loactionapth doesn't have throws clues at method signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only one way to do this: throw an unchecked exception:

```
locationPath returns [CustomParser xpathParser]  
 : ^(LOCATION_PATH relativeLocationPath) {throw new RuntimeException("No way!");}
 | ^(LOCATION_PATH absoluteLocationPath {$xpathParser=$absoluteLocationPath.xpathParser;})
 ;
```

If the compiler still complains (I can't remember, and I'm not able to test right now), add an `if(true)` in front of it:

```
locationPath returns [CustomParser xpathParser]  
 : ^(LOCATION_PATH relativeLocationPath) {if(true) throw new RuntimeException("No way!");}
 | ^(LOCATION_PATH absoluteLocationPath {$xpathParser=$absoluteLocationPath.xpathParser;})
 ;
```

Comment: OK I think this will work. But I tried with locationPath returns [CustomParser xpathParser] throws MyCustom Exception Then the method is generated with throws clause. But Antlr works say the grammar is incorrect.

Comment: It works when I extend my Exception class form runtime exception. Thanks for the help.